# Do inner bang patterns always force outer constructors in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

In Haskell, is there ever a situation where for a data type

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
import Control.DeepSeq

data D = D Int
```

the instance

```
instance NFData D where
  rnf (D !_) = ()
```

can have a different effect than the instance with another outer `!`:

```
instance NFData D where
  rnf !(D !_) = ()
```

My research:

- https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.6.3/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#bang-patterns-informal only talks about `let` bindings (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509399/tuple-bang-patterns) answer), which I think doesn't apply for function pattern matches like this.
- https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/BangPatterns#Thebasicidea says

  > A bang only really has an effect if it precedes a variable or wild-card pattern

  and

  > putting a bang before a pattern that forces evaluation anyway does nothing

  and I think

  - `rnf (D _)` already forces evaluation anyway

    - because it's like `rnf x = case x of D _ -> ...`
  - so `rnf !(D _)` would have the same effect as `rnf (D _)`
  - and thus by substitution `rnf !(D !_)` must have the same effect as `rnf (D !_)`

So I think *no, these two are always equivalent*, but I'm asking anyway to have one super clear answer to refer people to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed this is correct. We can see what is evaluated using `:sprint` in `GHCi`, which shows us what thunks have been evaluated.

With no bang patterns:

```
λ data D = D Int
λ d1 = D 1
λ :sprint d1
d1 = _
λ f1 (D _) = 0
λ f1 d1
0
λ :sprint d1
d1 = <D> _ -- Only D evaluated
```

With an inner bang pattern:

```
λ d2 = D 2
λ :sprint d2
d2 = _
λ f2 (D !_) = 0
λ f2 d2
0
λ :sprint d2
d2 = <D> 2 -- Everything evaluated
```

With an outer bang pattern:

```
λ d3 = D 3
λ :sprint d3
d3 = _
λ f3 !(D _) = 0
λ f3 d3
0
λ :sprint d3
d3 = <D> _ -- Only D evaluated
```

With an inner and outer bang patterns:

```
λ d4 = D 4
λ :sprint d4
d4 = _
λ f4 !(D !_) = 0
λ f4 d4
0
λ :sprint d4
d4 = <D> 4 -- Everything evaluated
```

From this we can easily see that the patterns `!(D !_)` and `(D !_)` are equivalent, and moreover that patterns of the form `!(D ...)` are redundant.